# Expanding SQL INSERT INTO Statement (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a current INSERT INTO function in Access VBA as follows:

```
INSERT INTO tblTest
SELECT  tblCountry_Language.Language ID
FROM    tblCountry_Language
        INNER JOIN tblTerritory_Country
            ON tblCountry_Language.Territory_CountryID = tblTerritory_Country.Territory_CountryID
WHERE   tblTerritory_Country.TerritoryID = "& [Forms]![frmInput].[Form]![TerritoryID]&";"
```

which works as desired; it basically grabs the listed languages from `tblCountry_Language` that match the territory specification of the user form.

NOTE: `tblCountry_Language` has the unique ID `Country_LanguageID`, and the fields `Territory_CountryID` and `LanguageID`. `tblTerritory_Country` is just a one to many table that details all of the countries that belong to each territory.

PROBLEM:
For new functionalities, I now want to bring in the  *associated* `CountryID` from `tblTerritory_Country` that each of those `LanguageID`'s is paired with from `tblCountry_Language`

The logic would look something like the following:

a)`LanguageID` directs to `Territory_CountryID` from `tblCountry_Language`,

b) and I can grab `CountryID` `Territory_CountryID` based on the connected `Territory_CountryID`

How can I make the INSERT INTO statement insert  *both*  `LanguageID` and `CountryID` ?

=================================   EDIT  #1 ================================

Here's a visualization of the tables:

```
tblTerritory_Country
Territory_CountryID -----TerritoryID ----- CountryID
                      |                |

tblCountry_Language
Country_LanguageID ----- Territory_CountryID ----- LanguageID
                     |               |               


tblTest
TestID ----- LanguageID ----- CountryID -----.....(More Irrelevant IDS)
         |                |               | ............
```

I want to add into the current INSERT INTO statement something that triangulates the matching `Country_ID` to the same `Territory_CountryID` used in the inner join, and use that ID to grab CountryID from `tblTerritory_Country` and then insert it into `tblTest`.

Comment: you can't. `insert` only allows one single table. if you want to target multiple tables, then you'll have to use multiple inserts - and preferably do it inside a transaction.

Comment: @MarcB - I think he's inserting this into a new table, so it's a matter of constructing the proper join statement.  potatosoup, can you maybe edit this question to include a little bit of sample data, even if it's made up.  I'm having difficulty visualizing how the data is related.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I added a visualization of the tables, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but I see people doing this a lot. `[Forms]![frmInput].[Form]![TerritoryID]` - the `.Form` in there is unnecessary. It's just a reference to `frmInput`. You could do also `Forms!frmInput.Form.Form.Form![TerritoryID]`, it would work too, but be just as unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the field.

```
INSERT INTO tblTest (LanguageID, CountryID)
SELECT  tblCountry_Language.LanguageID, tblTerritory_Country.CountryID
FROM    tblCountry_Language
INNER JOIN tblTerritory_Country ON tblCountry_Language.Territory_CountryID = tblTerritory_Country.Territory_CountryID
WHERE   tblTerritory_Country.TerritoryID = "& [Forms]![frmInput].[Form]![TerritoryID]&";"
```

Comment: Nice work @Hogan, solution a lot easier than what I expected. Thanks!

Comment: @potatosoup This is actually a basic building blocks of what sql does... Just wait... Your mind will soon be blown